# Publishing SSDT project using Web Publish in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, publish, sql-server-data-tools

I have been tasked with figuring out how to publish an SSDT project when a ASP.NET project is published using the Web One Click Publish in Visual Studio. I have created a publish profile for my SSDT project and can deploy the database objects manually using this publish profile.

For the Web Application I have also created a publish profile. This is my first time working with publish profiles, but I'm under the impression you can use any MSBuild commands in the web publish profile. I see the command to publish an SSDT project using MSBuild looks something like this:

> MSBuild /t:Publish
>   /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="myPublishFile.publish.xml"

My question is how do I add this to the web project's publish profile to deploy our SSDT projects when the web application is published? I have been doing some research and haven't come across anything like this.